# Clickable Text Render Actor

Tags: unreal-4, text

So I couldn't find anything online for this, but I want to make my text render actor clickable for my main menu. For example, when "New Game" is clicked it starts a new game. If you have any answers, please leave them for me! Tysm! :>

Comment: Please edit your question and provide information regarding what engine/framework/etc that you're using. Also provide information regarding what you've previously tried. Have you actually made any efforts on finding the answer you're seeking, by searching this site and/or a search engine?

Comment: @Daniel_1985, I've researched it and looked through many pages and the only thing I could find was a person who posted this same question somewhere else but never got answered. I usually learn from tutorials or Stack Exchange as I'm never really able to figure anything like this out on my own without a lot of help, so I haven't thought of anything to try. Also, I'm using UE4's latest version. Sorry, I always forget to mention the engine when I'm on the game dev Stack Exchange.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just use a opaque button with a text on top of it?

Comment: @Stephen I don't want to use a widget if that's what you mean.

Comment: Well it certainly possible - Enclose your TextRenderActor inside some collision box - and upon player clicks just line trace under mouse cursor and check if it hits the button - to make it better you can specify your own game specific trace channels -> you could specify a clicakble channel only for these mouse interactions.

Comment: @ColdSteel Tysm! It worked! :>